# Opening text file encoded in MacCentEuro on Windows10 or Ubuntu

Tags: encoding

I have been given a text file that contains strings that are not understandable when I open them in sublime3 or vscode. The programmer that gave me this file said that is encoded in MacCentEuro encoding. How can i open it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For VS Code as was not able to reopen with maccenteuro encoding, I found that if I added

```
"[hal]": { 
    "files.encoding": "maccenteuro"
    }
```

In this case hal is the file extension. everything worked well.